# insert to database (mysql) don't work in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, sql-insert

Inserting data into database in laravel don't work.
PHP Controller code:

```
public static function publish (Request $request) {
    $autor = session("name")." ".session("surname");
    $title = $request->title;
    $title2 = $request->title2;
    $titlePhoto = $request->titlePhoto;
    $text = $request->text;
    $category = $request->category;
    $tag = $request->tag;
    $source = $request->source;
    \DB::table("articles")->insertGetId(
        ["title" => $title, "autor" => $autor, "text" => $text, "title2" => $title2, "category" => $category, "titlephoto" => $titlePhoto, "tag" => $tag, "source" => $source]
    );
}
```

The request data are received by the controller.

I have in table another column: date but i want to keep them empty.
Laravel won't let me leave them empty. Display error: Field 'date' doesn't have a default value

if I change "\DB::table("articles")->insertGetId..." to "\DB::insert("INSERT INTO `articles` (`title`, `autor`, `title2`, `category`, `titlephoto`, `tag`, `source`) VALUES ('$title', '$autor', '$title2', '$category', '$titlePhoto', '$tag', '$source')");" it doesn't work either, but it doesn't return the error.

Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to empty date field you have 2 option:

1.add this key to insert array as blank `"date" => ""`

OR

2.modify date column as nullable

```
ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY date DATETIME
```

Comment: it doesn't work either. Error: Incorrect datetime value

Comment: So if you don't write your date data type, i can not know this. Please try 2. option. change date field as nullable

Comment: Date column is a datetime type. And error: Column 'date' cannot be null

Comment: Yes, because of your column structure. ALTER TABLE your_table MODIFY `date` DATETIME